# Infinite loop I can't find in BattleShips game python

Tags: python, loops

Hi I am pretty new to coding and i started a few days ago with this project. I learnt quite a bit in the process but now I am stuck with an infinite loop I can't find.
Sorry for naming variables in another language my main tongue isn't English.
Taulell_0 is a 10*10 array that i generate with another function
Anyways here's the code.
import random

```
def omple_taulell_ordinador():
    fragata=0    
    while fragata<1:
        vertical=random.randint(0,1)
        if vertical==0:
            filaf=random.randint(0,9)
            columnaf=random.randint(0,5)
            numf=0
            while numf<5:
                taulell_0[filaf][columnaf+numf]=1
                numf+=1
        else:
            filaf=random.randint(0,5)
            columnaf=random.randint(0,9)
            numf=0
            while numf<5:
                taulell_0[filaf+numf][columnaf]=1
                numf+=1
        fragata+=1
    #fragata feta per l'amor de deu!!
    cuirassats=0
    while cuirassats<2:
        vertical=random.randint(0,1)
        if vertical==0:
            filac=random.randint(0,9)
            columnac=random.randint(0,6)
            numc=0
            while numc<4:
                if taulell_0[filac][columnac:columnac+3]==0:
                    taulell_0[filac][columnac+numc]=1
                    numc+=1
                
                else:
                    filac=random.randint(0,9)
                    columnac=random.randint(0,6)
        else:
            filac=random.randint(0,6)
            columnac=random.randint(0.9)
            numc=0
            while numc<4:
                if taulell_0[filac:filac+3][columnac]==0:
                    taulell_0[filac+numc][columnac]=1
                    numc+=1
                else:
                    filac=random.randint(0,6)
                    columnac=random.randint(0,9)
        cuirassats+=1        
        
    return taulell_0
            
for i in omple_taulell_ordinador():
    print (i)
```

Comment: You need to be more specific with your question/problem. I suspect your issue is in your `while numc<4:` loops, the `else` clauses do not increment `numc`

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this:

```
        while numc<4:
            if taulell_0[filac][columnac:columnac+3]==0:
                taulell_0[filac][columnac+numc]=1
                numc+=1
            
            else:
                filac=random.randint(0,9)
                columnac=random.randint(0,6)
```

In that `while` loop, if the `if` condition is never met, the loop could go on forever.

Answer (score 0):

```
if taulell_0[filac][columnac:columnac+3]==0:
```

Returns a list that looks something like `[0, 0, 0]`.

That cannot equal `0`, so the condition is never true, and `numc` is never incremented.

Perhaps you want this?

```
if sum(taulell_0[filac][columnac:columnac+3])==0:
```